# Running multiple Django projects within Apache, sys.path being over written

Tags: centos, python, httpd, django, mod-wsgi

I have been trying to research how to do a multiple Python / Django deployment using Apache VirtualHosts.

The issue I am encountering seems straight forward,

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'hub.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named hub.settings, referer: proposals.internal.local
```

The trouble I am having is that proposals.internal.local is using proposals.settings and the hub.settings is actually from hub.internal.local.

If I run just proposal or hub on their own, I do not encounter the above mentioned problem, however, when I do run them both - as people use them. The sys.path seems to be updated for both of the projects.

[APACHE CONFIGS - HUB]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName hub.internal.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/hub.internal.local/hub/hub/static
    Alias /static/  /var/www/hub.internal.local/hub/hub/static/

    <Directory /var/www/hub.internal.local/hub/hub/static>

        Allow from all

    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/hub.internal.local/hub/hub/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

[APACHE CONFIGS - PROPOSALS]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName proposals.internal.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/proposals.internal.local/proposal/proposal/static
    Alias /static/  /var/www/proposals.internal.local/proposal/proposal/static/

    <Directory /var/www/proposals.internal.local/proposal/proposal/static>

        Allow from all

    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/proposals.internal.local/proposal/proposal/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

[wsgi.py - HUB]

```
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hub.settings")
sys.path.append('/var/www/hub.internal.local')
sys.path.append('/var/www/hub.internal.local/hub')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

[wsgi.py - PROPOSALS]

```
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "proposal.settings")
sys.path.append('/var/www/proposals.internal.local')
sys.path.append('/var/www/proposals.internal.local/proposal')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Clearly I am missing something but I am not seeing anything unusual from the documentation.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use `os.environ.setdefault()`. Django screwed up the hosting of multiple applications in one mod_wsgi process when they switched to that way of setting environment variables.

This is documented in my blog: [Requests running in wrong Django instance under Apache/mod_wsgi.](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html)

> There are two solutions if this is the cause. The quickest is to
>   replace the use of setdefault() to set the environment variable in the
>   WSGI script file with more usual assignment.
>
> ```
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
> ```
>
> An alternative which involves a bit more work, but can have other
>   benefits, is to switch to using daemon mode of mod_wsgi to run the
>   Django instances and delegate each to a separate set of processes. By
>   running the Django instances in separate processes there can be no
>   possibility of environment variables leaking from one to the other.
>
> ```
> WSGIDaemonProcess project-2
> WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /some/path/project-2/wsgi.py process-group=project-2
>
> WSGIDaemonProcess project-1
> WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/project-1/wsgi.py process-group=project-1
> ```

Comment: Hi,This is the fix I have used: 

WSGIDaemonProcess project-2 WSGIScriptAlias /suburl /some/path/project-2/wsgi.py process-group=project-2

WSGIDaemonProcess project-1 WSGIScriptAlias / /some/path/project-1/wsgi.py process-group=project-1

and this resolved the issue.

Thank you so much.