# How do I configure Apache to work with multiple Django apps?

Tags: apache2

I want to run multiple Django project on Apache2 server. So if I type in my url:

`localhost/OpenGMS`

my `OpenGMS` project would run in the apache2 server and if I type in the url:

`localhost/my_other_site`

my other project will run in the apache2 server.

To do this I configured the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. It looks like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName OpenGMS.org
    ServerAlias www.OpenGMS.org
    ServerAdmin samsadsajid@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/OpenGMS

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/OpenGMS/OpenGMS/wsgi.py

    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And also configured `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. I added a single line at the end of the file. The line is

`WSGIPythonPath /var/www/OpenGMS`

I find a question related to this [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/566517/running-multiple-django-projects-within-apache-sys-path-being-over-written). It says that

> An alternative which involves a bit more work, but can have other
>   benefits, is to switch to using daemon mode of mod_wsgi to run the
>   Django instances and delegate each to a separate set of processes. By
>   running the Django instances in separate processes there can be no
>   possibility of environment variables leaking from one to the other.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess project-2 WSGIScriptAlias /suburl
> /some/path/project-2/wsgi.py process-group=project-2
```

> 

```
 WSGIDaemonProcess project-1 WSGIScriptAlias /
> /some/path/project-1/wsgi.py process-group=project-1
```

Then I configured the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` again. It looked like this:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName OpenGMS.org
    ServerAlias www.OpenGMS.org
    ServerAdmin samsadsajid@gmail.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/OpenGMS

    WSGIDaemonProcess my_other_site 
    WSGIScriptAlias /my_other_site /var/www/my_other_site/my_other_site/wsgi.py process-group=my_other_site


    WSGIDaemonProcess OpenGMS
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/OpenGMS/OpenGMS/wsgi.py process-group=OpenGMS

    ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But I didn't configure the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file.

Now when I run the `localhost/OpenGMS` or/and `localhost/my_other_site` I get internal server error 500.

Is the error happening because I didn't edit the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` after adding a new site in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` or there are some other things I am doing wrong or don't know?

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use entries in your /etc/hosts file. You can then refer to localhost by different names and then have different virtualhost entries.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1     localhost host1 host2 host3 host4
```

You can now refer to localhost by any of the other names
http://host1/
http://host2/

And then have your virtual host for each

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host1 
    ... 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host2
```